# An integral approximation for $Q = \sum_x f(x) $ when $\tan(C x) = x$

Tags: integration, summation, approximate-integration

I have a sum of the form
$$Q = \sum_{x}f(x).$$
Here, the $x$ entering the sum are the countably infinite set of solutions to
$$ \tan(C x) = x.$$
The $x$ are not integers, but they do satisfy
$$ \frac{\pi}{2C}(2n+1)\leq x_n \leq \frac{\pi}{2C}(2n+3),$$
where the $n$ are integers.

I am interested in the case of large $C$. In the limit of large $C$, successive solutions to $\tan(C x)=x$ become closer and closer together, separated by a gap $x_{n+1}-x_n = \pi/C$, so we can imagine writing a kind of Reimann sum for $Q$, although I am unclear how to do this.

Is it possible to write

$$Q \approx \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) w(x) dx ?$$
If so, how do I obtain the weight function $w(x)$?

Comment: Solutions to this equation that are not close to $0$ are very nearly and arithmetic sequence, for reasos easily seen by looking at superimposed graphs of $x\mapsto\tan(Cx)$ and $x\mapsto x.$ In order that the sum approximate the integral, you would have to multiply the terms in the sum by the sizes of the gaps between solutions. At this point I'm wondering whether the difference between the integral and that sum (with the gap-size factor) would depend a lot on what happens with solutions near $0.$ If not, you'd probably get a good approximation to the integral.

Comment: Yes Michael I agree - I think that the approximation will only be good if $f(x)$ decays slowly as $|x|$ grows from $0$, for reasons relating to the physical problem giving the equation. Otherwise if $f(x)$ decays rapidly, one can use just the first terms of the sum as a good approximation. But this essentially makes sense... $\sum_x f(x) \approx \frac{\pi}{C}\int f(x) dx.$ I will see if the result makes physical sense, and then that's good enough for me . . .

Comment: His name was RIEMANN , not REIMANN.